# why manipulating property at prototype chain actually Creates it on object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I think best way to demonstrate what i am saying is show the code that tells the story itself...

```
function Animal() {this.lives=7;}
function Cat() {} 
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
cat1 = new Cat();

for (var i in cat1) { if (cat1.hasOwnProperty(i)) { console.log(i);}}
//undefined  --as expected since property lives exists in prototype chain, Cat.prototype.

//but when i do this
cat1.lives -= 1;

// and now if i run this again
for (var i in cat1) { if (cat1.hasOwnProperty(i)) { console.log(i);}}
// lives -- How?? I just manipulated property in proto chain i didnt do obj.val = 3; which would create a new property.
```

and just to be complete.. if i do

```
Cat.prototype.lives = 10;
```

then

```
cat1.prototype.lives; // 6
```

Comment: What is `cat1.prototype.lives`? Did you mean `cat1.lives`?

Comment: cat1 didn't have its own lives property, so i thought if i do `cat1.lives` and get property in proto chain then if i do `cat1.lives = 3;` then i'm changing property in proto chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype chain will be used only for resolving the value. But when you are assigning something, then the property will be created on the object.

You can think of

```
cat1.lives -= 1;
```

as

```
cat1.lives = cat1.lives - 1;
```

And here, first the right hand side expression is evaluated. So, `cat1.lives` is resolved to be `7`, as per the prototype chain. But, when you are assigning it, the `lives` property is created on the `cat1` object itself.

Comment: that's what i think it appears to be, when assigning property it gets assigned to object even thought it can be resolved/exists in proto chain. So to manipulate a property, not method, one needs to define setters. And is this documented anywhere.

Comment: `cat1.lives = cat1.lives - 1;` part explains it to me, makes it work with my model of how js logic works.